# Add class after waiting a dynamic amount of time

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hide, show-hide

I'm hoping to blur an element out then give it a style of `display: none` to remove it completely from the document. The code below isn't working properly: The `setTimeout` function I think is executing too fast.

How could I alter my code to allow the `duration` parameter of the `updateClassAndRemove` function to add `duration` seconds to the animation and the same amount of seconds to the `setTimeout` function as intended?

```js
// \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INTIAL /////////////////////////////// //
'use strict';

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ REMOVE ELEMENT / / / / / / / / / / / / ///
function removeElement( element ){
  element.classList.add( 'dsp-none');
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / REMOVE ELEMENT \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\\

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ UPDATE CLASS AND REMOVE / / / / / / / / / / //
function updateClassAndRemove( element, classString, duration ){
  element.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
  element.classList.add( classString );
// The below line appears to hide the element too fast
//  setTimeout ( removeElement( element ), duration * 1000 ); 
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / UPDATE CLASS AND REMOVE / / / / / / / / / / //

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ START / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //
function start(){
  var element = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' );
  updateClassAndRemove( element, 'blur', 10 );
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / START \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\

start();
```

```css
/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
.dsp-none {
  display: none;
}

/* \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION DEFINITIONS / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
.animation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.blur {
  animation-name: blur;
}

/*\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION KEYFRAMES / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
@keyframes blur {
  100% {
    filter: blur( 1rem );
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="animation">Blur this, then remove display.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `removeElement()` inside of a function in `setTimeout`

```js
// \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INTIAL /////////////////////////////// //
'use strict';

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ REMOVE ELEMENT / / / / / / / / / / / / ///
function removeElement( element ){
  element.classList.add( 'dsp-none');
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / REMOVE ELEMENT \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\\

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ UPDATE CLASS AND REMOVE / / / / / / / / / / //
function updateClassAndRemove( element, classString, duration ){
  element.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
  element.classList.add( classString );
  setTimeout(function() {
    removeElement( element );
  }, duration * 1000);
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / UPDATE CLASS AND REMOVE / / / / / / / / / / //

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ START / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //
function start(){
  var element = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' );
  updateClassAndRemove( element, 'blur', 10 );
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / START \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\

start();
```

```css
/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
.dsp-none {
  display: none;
}

/* \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION DEFINITIONS / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
.animation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.blur {
  animation-name: blur;
}

/*\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION KEYFRAMES / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
@keyframes blur {
  100% {
    filter: blur( 1rem );
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="animation">Blur this, then remove display.</p>
```

---

**Note:** A way of calling `setTimeout` with less code: 
`setTimeout ( removeElement, duration * 1000, element );`

---

Or you can use the `animationend` event.

```js
// \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INTIAL /////////////////////////////// //
'use strict';

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ REMOVE ELEMENT / / / / / / / / / / / / ///
function removeElement( element ){
  element.classList.add( 'dsp-none');
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / REMOVE ELEMENT \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\\

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ UPDATE CLASS AND REMOVE / / / / / / / / / / //
function updateClassAndRemove( element, classString, duration ){
  element.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
  element.addEventListener('animationend',function() {
    removeElement( element );
  })
  element.classList.add( classString );
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / UPDATE CLASS AND REMOVE / / / / / / / / / / //

// \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ START / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / //
function start(){
  var element = document.getElementById( 'paragraph' );
  updateClassAndRemove( element, 'blur', 10 );
}
// / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / START \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\

start();
```

```css
/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
.dsp-none {
  display: none;
}

/* \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION DEFINITIONS / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
.animation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.blur {
  animation-name: blur;
}

/*\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION KEYFRAMES / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
@keyframes blur {
  100% {
    filter: blur( 1rem );
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" class="animation">Blur this, then remove display.</p>
```

Comment: This is good answer but I found out I had syntax wrong. This is cleaner `setTimeout ( removeElement, duration * 1000, element ); ` I didn't know how to pass parameters like this. Update your answer? https://jsfiddle.net/w0wueccv/

Comment: @ngwazi sure, is that why you chose not to accept my answer? It's just another way of writing it. If you prefer it being written with the var passed as the third parameter, can you edit my post and I'll accept it?